# AlertDialog.Builder How Can I Access the the 'PositiveButton'?

Tags: android

I am using `AlertDialog.Builder` to create a dialog with a `EditText` and two buttons, `'OK'` and `'Cancel'`. I create the OK and Cancel buttons with `AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton()` and `.setNegativeButton()` respectively. The purpose of the dialog is to request an I.P. address from the user.

Initially I want to have the OK button disabled and attach to the `EditText` an `OnKey listener` so that when the user types the onKey listener is called and I can check the current `EditText` value with a regular expression for a valid IP address. Should a valid IP address be entered I'd then want to enable the OK button, but as I use the `setPositiveButton()` I have no idea what the id of the button is.

Can I get the id of the OK button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need the id of the button,all you need is to implement `DialogInterface.onClickListener()`

In the onKeyListener() you add some test if the field is filled with correct input or not

`dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(enabled);`

And for the click listener of the OK button. Remember that you need to set the button before you do `.getButton()`

```
  dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Do what you want when the user presses the Ok button

                }});
```

Comment: It doesnt matter, mate :D We help people, either ways :D